# Determine power series representations for function

Tags: calculus, power-series

Function $$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$$
The way I started this question is by starting from the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$, I took out $\frac{1}{2}$ and then wrote the adequate power series with $\frac{x}{2}^n$. After differentiating I get a solution that is nowhere near the solution in my book. Can someone please guide me with where I made a mistake?

Comment: if you show your work, perhaps someone could point out your mistake

Comment: If you "take out the $2$", you have $$\frac14\left(1-\frac x2\right)^{-2}$$  What did you do about the exponent?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac1{(2-x)^2}=\dfrac14\dfrac1{\left(1-\frac x2\right)^2}=\dfrac14\left(1+2\dfrac x2+3\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2+4\left(\dfrac x2\right)^3\cdots\right),$$

because $$\dfrac1{(1-y)^2}=\dfrac d{dy}\dfrac1{1-y}=\dfrac d{dy}(1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+\cdots)=1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Comment:
You may use following relation:

$$\frac1{(1+x)^2}=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3 + \cdot \cdot \cdot (-1)^r(r+1)x^r$$

$2-x=1+(1-x)$

So  substituting x by $1-x$ must give you the result.